# It is possible to combine two heavy elements into one?

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion, stability, binding-energy

Is it possible to combine say two uranium atoms into very heavy new element? Periodic table ends around 115 today, but can it go forever technically?

Answer (score 2):

Not with any stability.

Elements other than those already either found or hypothesized are thought to be unstable, this is increasingly true the greater the number of neucleons in the nucleus. The structural configuration of protons and neutrons prevents a stable state and they undergo either spontaneous fission or alpha decay. Element 117 has a half-life ([t<sub>1/2</sub>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-life)) of less than 1 second, for example.

There is an "island of stability" forecast to be able to be produced and remain stable for a useful amount of time:

[image: A 3-dimensional representation of the theoretical Island of stability in nuclear physics.]

<sup>[CCASA 3.0 unported](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en), by InvaderXan. Image via [extremetech](https://www.extremetech.com/extreme/220259-periodic-table-gains-four-new-superheavy-elements-completing-the-seventh-row) 2023.</sup>

The nucleus at the island is thought to form a particular configuration, in this case spherical which is stable.